# php foreach loop multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [14] => 15 [15] => 16 [16] => 17 [17] => 18 [18] => 19 [19] => 20 [20] => 21 [21] => 22 [22] => 23 [23] => 24 [24] => 25 [25] => 26 [26] => 27 [27] => 28 [28] => 29 [29] => 30 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 [25] => 1 [26] => 1 [27] => 1 [28] => 1 [29] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 [25] => 1 [26] => 1 [27] => 1 [28] => 1 [29] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 [25] => 1 [26] => 1 [27] => 1 [28] => 1 [29] => 1 ) ) )
```

I can access the data like this:

```
print_r($ps[0][0]);
print_r($ps[0][1]);
print_r($ps[0][2]);
print_r($ps[0][3]);
```

How can I separate it in a foreach loop I mean each second key?

Comment: Write code. That's your job. We (maybe) try help fix whatever you do end up producing.

Comment: If there is only `$ps[0]` and not more like `$ps[1]` then loop `$ps[0]`.  If more then 2 loops.

Comment: you mean something like this: foreach($ps[0] as $key => $p) {?

Comment: @user995691 give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($ps[0]); $i++) {
        foreach ($ps[0][$i] as $p) {
            echo $p.'<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you showed an attempt (in an answer), you can use two `foreach`:

```
foreach($ps[0] as $array) {
    foreach($array as $p) {
        echo "$p<br/>";
    }
}
```